# Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I've uninstalled java, installed 7 update 65 and switched the executable, but Minecraft still does not run. What should I do? On my other computer everything is the same for the .exe file and arguments are also the same, yet it runs on that computer. Here is my stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil.<init>(PropertiesUtil.java:71)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil.<clinit>(PropertiesUtil.java:31)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.status.StatusLogger.<clinit>(StatusLogger.java:48)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:44)
at ave.<clinit>(SourceFile:145)
at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:41)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ProviderUtil.<clinit>(ProviderUtil.java:70)
... 6 more
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release`
```

Comment: What you have in the title is a warning, not an error. It's not going to be the reason you can't get the game to run, so please provide more info.

Comment: @Thebluefish i have entered the full log.